# Triangle Inequality with complex numbers: Prove that $ |z_{1} - z_{2}| \le |z_{1}| + |z_{2}| $.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Prove that $ |z_{1} - z_{2}| \le |z_{1}| + |z_{2}| $ for all $ z_{1},z_{2} \in \mathbb{C} $.

I don’t quite get how to deal with these triangle-inequality proofs, so any extra insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you asking for a proof?

Comment: Yes and insight on how to approach similar problems.

Comment: Is it something like what Dimitri did that you were looking for?

Comment: Yes i think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or similarly : 
$$z_1 = a_1 + i b_1, z_2 = a_2 + i b_2, \Rightarrow $$
$$
|z_1 - z_2 |^2 = |(a_1 - a_2) + i(b_1 - b_2)|^2  = (a_1 - a_2)^2 + (b_1 - b_2)^2 = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + b_1^2 + b_2^2 - 2a_1a_2 - 2b_1b_2 \leq  ( |z_1|+|z_2| )^2
$$

Answer (score 7):

$$|z_1 - z_2| = |z_1 + (-z_2)| \leq |z_1| + |-z_2| = |z_1| + |z_2|$$

where the inequality is exactly the triangle inequality.